# Using ffmpeg to split audio file at a particular tone

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have a system that creates audio files of automated fire dispatches as wav files, and occasionally the file will record multiple calls separated by a multi-tone sequence. [Here is a sample](http://tfscad.victorbiro.com/3Calls.wav)

I have been searching for a way to have ffmpeg, or some other Linux CLI tool, recognise the tones and then cut the file into a separate WAV file named `[unixtimestamp of original]+duration seconds.wav`

Does anyone have any ideas?